# How to set a list within an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I initiated a multidimensional array:

```
private byte[,] grid = new byte[9, 9];
```

I want to hold a byte List with some values, for each cell withing the existing grid.

I know a 3 dimensional array would be handy here. But since the list with invalid values is dynamical, I would like to use a List instead of an array.

**Edit:** To give some context here. I'm making a sudoku, which is represented by a multidimensional array. Since I would like to solve the sudoku programmatically and I'm using the backtrack algorithm, I need to remember the digits that where invalid for each cell.

So each cell should consist of a value and a List. I could probably just put the actual field as first value in the list. But never know if there is an actual clean solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var grid = new List<byte>[9,9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        grid[i, j] = new List<byte>();
```

After that every item of 9x9 array contains an empty `List<byte>`.

However, I would suggest creating a class like `Field`

```
public class Field
{
    public byte Value { get; set; }
    public List<byte> List { get; set; }

    public Field()
    {
        List = new List<byte>();
    }
}
```

And use it instead of just `List<byte>`:

```
var grid = new Field[9, 9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        grid[i, j] = new Field();
```

Comment: Ty for reply. Seems the same as C Sharper suggested. I will try that if there is no other solution. Since it's indeed closer to my likings then an 3dimensional array.

Comment: Ooooow, Yes indeed. That I didn't though about that >< That was stupid :p Well, tyvm sir

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need a list of bytes in a list?
Try this:

```
  List<List<byte>> listOfBytesInList = new List<List<byte>>();
```

**Update**

You can implement a own class that uses internal a list of bytes.
I'm too late, but regardless I post my solution anyway.

```
 public class ByteFieldList
    {
        private readonly List<byte> _interalBytes;

        public ByteFieldList()
            : this(4, 0)
        {
        }

        public ByteFieldList(byte fieldValue)
            : this(4, fieldValue)
        {
        }


        public ByteFieldList(int capacity, byte fieldValue)
        {
            FieldValue = fieldValue;
            _interalBytes = new List<byte>(capacity);
        }


        public byte FieldValue { get; set; }

        public ByteFieldList Add(byte b)
        {
            _interalBytes.Add(b);
            return this;
        }

        public void AddRange(byte[] bytes)
        {
            foreach (var b in bytes)
                Add(b);
        }


        public ByteFieldList Remove(byte b)
        {
            _interalBytes.Remove(b);
            return this;
        }

        public byte this[int index]
        {
            get { return _interalBytes[index]; }
        }

        public byte[] GetAllInvalid()
        {
            return _interalBytes.ToArray();
        }   

    }


  public void Usage()
        {
            ByteFieldList byteFieldList = new ByteFieldList(5);

            byteFieldList.Add(5).Add(4).Add(8);
            byteFieldList.AddRange(new byte[] { 7, 89, 4, 32, 1 });

            var invalids = byteFieldList.GetAllInvalid(); // get 5, 4, 8, 7, 89, 4, 32, 1

            byteFieldList.FieldValue = 4;

        }
```

Comment: Didn't though about that. But I would still need an actual field. So 1 cell should consists of an actual field with byte value and a list of type byte.